# Renaming MM.DD.YY files to YY.MM.DD with .bat

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a .bat file which iterates through every file in the directory which the .bat file is in, and renames all the files which follow the naming convention of `MM_DD_YY*.*` to `YY_MM_DD*.*`.

For example, `05.20.16 MyFile.txt` would become `16.05.20 MyFile.txt`.

I've managed to iterate through the filenames, but I'm having trouble with making a substring of the beginning 8 characters and comparing them to the format of `##.##.##`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpression
for /f %%i in ('dir /b') do (
set fn=%%i
:: Need to compare first 8 chars to ##.##.##
if %fn:~0,8%==??.??.?? echo FollowsFormat
)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided:

- the date in the file name is always followed by a space.

You can use delimiters `.`  and `space`to seperate date elements and remaining file name into for variables `%%A` - `%%D` and rearrange them in the desired order.

To better distinguish old from new format I suggest to change the delimiter (at least temporarily) to a `-` and extend the year to 4 digits.

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpression
for /f "tokens=1-3* delims=. " %%A in (
  'dir /b /A-D "??.??.?? *.txt" ^| findstr "^[01][0-9]\.[0-3][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9].*"' 
) do Echo Ren "%%A.%%B.%%C %%D" "20%%C-%%A-%%B %%D"
```

For security reason the batch only echoes what it would rename
until you remove the echo in front of ren if the output looks OK.